# Kafka consumer offset commit when later message is consumed first

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a java Kafka consumer in which I am fetching ConsumerRecords in a batch to process. The sample code is as follows -

```
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for  (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
        DoSomeProcessing (record.value());
    }
    consumer.commitAsync();
}

private void DoSomeProcessing(String record) {
    //make an external call to a system which can take random time for different requests or timeout in 5 seconds.
}
```

The problem I have is for how or which offset to commit if the later record is produced but the previous record is still not timed out.
Lets suppose I get 2 records in a batch, the external call for 1st message is still awaited, and for 2nd call completed. If I wait for 5 seconds for the external response, the consumption from Kafka message can become super slow in cases. If I do not wait for 1st request to complete before doing another poll, what offset do I commit to Kafka? If I commit 2, and if the consumer crashes, 1st message will be lost as next time latest committed offset would be 2.

Answer (score 6):

I think you analyzed the problem correctly, and the answer is probably what you suspect: you can't commit offsets until every offset less than and equal to that offset has been processed. That's just how Kafka works: it's very much oriented around strong ordering.

The solution is to increase the number of partitions and consumers so you get the parallelism you desire. This is not great from some angles—you needs more threads and resources—but at least you get to write synchronous code.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I understand adding more partitions and consumers in the group would help, but the problem would still remain. Lets suppose in the upper use case a message is always going to fail(for e.g it is a push notification delivery to a mobile and the mobile is offline). All the following messages in the partition would never be processed, however high is the parallelism. Even if the partition gets reassigned to new consumer, the failed message will continue to fail and later message in the partition will never be committed.

Comment: Yeah, in such a use case you’d do something like write the failed message to a “failed” topic and move on. Then you’d process the “failed” topic later, perhaps in a job. It is unsatisfactory, I know.

Comment: I understand, but if the time to decide if a message is failing is much more than the speed of message production, very high parallelism will be needed in the consumer group even if you are using multiple parallel threads to process in parallel. And all that just for committing the correct offset. IMHO, there is scope of improvement in consumer design.

Comment: What did you use that @HarshKumar ? I am also facing the same problem and a "failed" topic seems the only solution to me.

Comment: @Sumit - I had to optimize at few places to get the desired SLA in case of failures.
1. Increased the number of partitions and ran more consumer instances for more parallelism.
2. Passed the processing in parallel using a thread pool in each consumer.
3. Wait for all the calls to complete. If any of them fails, retry failed ones 3 times tops before running next poll.
4. For the failed ones, write the failed ones to DB for manual handling. 

Could not find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you can setup an error pipeline. For the messages that are failing, you will commit that message and push it to the error queue and will process it later.